# Trying to create grouped records with linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have records like this in 1 list :

```
Id     Title     Name      Basic     Message
10     Stats2    abc       10         sldjs
10     Stats2    pqr       20         sldjs
10     Stats2    xyz       30         sldjs
10     Stats2    abc       40         sldjs


11     Stats3    aaa       0         sldjs
11     Stats3    bbb       0         sldjs
11     Stats3    ccc       0         sldjs
11     Stats3    ddd       0         sldjs
```

I have a variable of type List of class which hold below records:

```
var list = new List<Stats>();//this variable hold all above records.
```

Now I am trying to create records like below from list variable :

```
[0]:Stats2:
        abc         
            10  sldjs
            40  sldjs
        pqr
            20  sldjs
        xyz
            30  sldjs

[1]:Stats3:
        aaa         
            0  sldjs
        bbb
            0  sldjs
        ccc
            0  sldjs
        ddd 
            0  sldjs
```

This is how I am trying but not getting how to create inner nested children like (**2 abc records shown above**):

```
var data =list.GroupBy(ed =>ed.Id)
               .Select
               (

               )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group the inner records as well. The result could be something like a `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<Stats>>>`. The keys of the outer dictionary would be the `ID` values and the inner keys the `Name` values and the values would be lists of the `Stats` having that `Title` and `Name`:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(rec => rec.ID)
                 .ToDictionary(
                     group => group.Key,
                     group => group.GroupBy(stat => stat.Name)
                                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList())
                              );
```

You can access the values in the result like that:

```
result[10]["abc"]
```

The above example would be a list containing the `Stats` with `Basic`10 and 40.

---

If you only want to keep `Basic` and `Message` in the final records, you can use `Select` to project the `Stats` to an anonymous type:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(rec => rec.ID)
                 .ToDictionary(
                     group => group.Key,
                     group => group.GroupBy(stat => stat.Name)
                                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(stat => new {stat.Title, stat.Basic, stat.Message}).ToList())
                              );
```

Comment: Dont you think that your first group by should be on Id instead of title?

Comment: @Learning Not if you expect the results you show in your question. Your example results are first grouped by `Title` and then by `Name`, never by `ID`.

Comment: @Learning I just realized that (coincidently?) these groups would be the same, at least for your sample data. All `Stats2` have `ID` 10, but I can't see if this is always the case in your original data. But in your example result you used `Title` as key, thatswhy I used it too.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but i have a concern that suppose i have records with id 12 with same title Stats2 then i would like to have 3 result :[0]:Stats2 [1]:Stats3 [2]:Stats2

Comment: @Learing ok I update my answer...simply use ID instead of Title.

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me.Thanks once again and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var data =list.GroupBy(p => p.Title).Select(p => new
            {
                Title = p.Key,
                Items = p.GroupBy(q => q.Name)
                         .ToDictionary(q => q, q => new { q.Basic, q.Message })
            });
```

Comment: Dont you think that your first group by should be on Id instead of title?

Comment: @Learning, Based on your output you grouped the result with Title so am i.

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me but i have a concern that suppose i have records with id 12 with same title Stats2 then i would like to have 3 result :[0]:Stats2 [1]:Stats3 [2]:Stats2

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and please keep helping like this :)